# django custom file storage path

Tags: django

i would like to dynamically set the file storage path from the view regardless of the actual media_root path. is this possible. i have looked into custom storage objects and i am aware of the custom upload_to method call. currently i have a method that is called when my ImageField model upload_to is specified. this lets me change the directory within media_root. i have tried to do something similar with an overriden FileSystemStorage class but whatever it is set to i think it is bound before i can modify it within a view. if fileupload handler is the way to go i would be curious as to how to implement one.

Answer (score 1):

If path that you specified in `upload_to` starts with `/` then it will be considered as absolute path.  Through this you can set any path that you want regardless of `MEDIA_ROOT`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in your view `path = default_storage.save(filePath, ContentFile(file))`
where filePath is file path where you need to store, and file is the file which is uploaded by user. this function will return you the path by storing file.

```
file = request.FILES['filee']
filePath = '%s/%s' % ('path/to/directory', file.name)
file = file.read()
path = default_storage.save(filePath, ContentFile(file))
```